# Dúvida Sobre lógica de Socket

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma dúvida em relação a identificar socket. Vamos supor que eu tenha 2 "tipos de socket", um cliente e um atendente. Onde é feito o chat dos 2, posso ter vários clientes e vários atendentes, porém a minha dúvida é, como identificar cada um?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma, mas não sei se é uma boa prática ou se há maneiras melhores.

Tenho a classe Servidor, que recebe o Socket e instancia uma Classe `Gerencia_Socket`, ao receber a primeira mensagem, define se o socket é um cliente ou atendente, se for cliente, cria um objeto do tipo `Gerencia_Cliente`, onde tem todas as informações do cliente, se for atendente cria do tipo `Gerencia_Atendente`, com a informação do atendente.

É viável fazer isso? Pois já tenho 6 classes

- `Servidor`
- `Gerencia_Socket`
- `Gerencia_Cliente`
- `Gerencia_Atendente`
- `Atendente` (Próprio Socket)
- `Cliente` (Próprio Socket)

Agradeço desde já !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você pode utilizar classes herdadas para determinar qual o tipo de socket, porém no caso que você descreveu talvez seja mais simples se você apenas criar duas variáveis de lista na classe servidor da seguinte forma:

```
private final List<Gerencia_Socket> atendentes = new ArraysList<>();
private final List<Gerencia_Socket> clientes = new ArraysList<>();
```

No momento em que seja identificado o tipo de socket, adicione a lista correspondente da seguinte forma:

```
atendentes.add(novoAtendente);
```

Só haverá necessidade de criar outras classes caso haja algum comportamento divergente entre os sockets, porém no caso que você descreveu não há motivo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta :)